# cambiar de mysql a mysqli

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli

Hola tengo este código de conexión a mi base de datos y quería ver si me pueden ayudar a cambiarlo a mysqli manteniendo los mismos parámetros

```
<?php
function conectar(){
    $servidor   = "localhost";
    $usuario    = "root";
    $clave      = "123456789";
    $bd         = "inventario";

    if(!($link = mysql_connect($servidor,$usuario,$clave))){
        echo "ERROR DE CONEXION CON EL SERVIDOR";
        exit();
    }

    if(!mysql_select_db($bd,$link)){
        echo "ERROR DE CONEXION CON LA BASE DE DATOS";
        exit();     
    }

    return $link;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende que paradigmas elijas para trabajar, por ejemplo si es orientado a objetos tu código puede quedar de este modo:

```
<?php 

function conectar(){
    $servidor   = "localhost";
    $usuario    = "root";
    $clave      = "password";
    $bd         = "database";

    $conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $bd);

    if($conexion->connect_errno){
        return $conexion->connect_error;
    }else{
        return $conexion;
    }
}
```

- Se realiza la instancia de la clase `mysqli`a la variable `$conexion`
- verificamos si existe un error y en caso negativo retornamos dentro de la función a la `$conexion`

Ahora si queremos hacer una consulta a la base de datos, podemos asignar a una variable las funcionalidad de la función `conectar()` así:

```
$conecta = conectar();
```

Ahora podemos realizar la consulta de este modo:

```
$consulta = $conecta->query("SELECT * FROM tabla");

while($fila = $consulta->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $fila["columna"];
```

- La variable `$consulta` es igualada a la variable `$conecta` que permite el acceso al servidor de BD y esta a su vez accede al método `query` que recibe como parámetro en forma de *string* la consulta a ejecutar
- Como existe la posibilidad de iterar sobre múltiples datos hacemos uso de un *while* y del método `fetch_assoc` para volver los resultados de la query en un array asociativo
- Como se generó un array asociativo ahora por dentro del bucle podemos acceder a los elementos por medio del nombre de la columna así: `$variable["columna"]`

Desde un enfoque procedimental:

```
<?php 

function conectar(){
    $servidor   = "localhost";
    $usuario    = "root";
    $clave      = "password";
    $bd         = "database";

    $conexion = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $clave, $bd);

    if(!$conexion){
        return mysqli_connect_errno();
    }else{
        return $conexion;
    }
}

$conecta = conectar();

$consulta = mysqli_query($conecta, "SELECT * FROM tabla");

while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)){
    echo $fila["columna"];
}
```

- La mayoría de los métodos tienen el prefijo `mysqli_*` identificando al driver en uso
- La verificación de conexión se hace revisando si `$conexión` devuelve *true* o *false* con el operador de negación `!`
- El método `mysqli_query` recibe 2 parámetros uno es la variable de la conexión y el segundo es la consulta
- Para convertir el array en asociativo se usa el método `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` que recibe como parámetro la variable de la consulta.

**Enlaces**

- [MySQLi Class](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mysqli.php)

Answer (score 1):

Básicamente, dado que no tienes funciones muy complejas sino más bien sólo te conectas a la base de datos, según la [documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php) puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect($servidor, $usuario, $password, $bd);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error al conectar la base de datos" . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}

echo "Conexión exitosa" . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Para las funciones básicas es simple. Sustituyes los nombre de las funciones **mysql_*** por **mysqli_***